# Adding doubles with a while loop

Tags: java

I have been working on loops for the past week, and I still dont understand how this works. Basically i have a file containing some salires, i need to add them together using a while loop. I have been stuck on this problem for hours with no sense :/
Thanks!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: If you're going to answer this question, you should give hints (rather than doing the OP's homework for him).

Answer (score 2):

Create a double variable an initialize it to zero, then at each iteration of the while loop, add the salary to that variable.

```
double total = 0;

while(termination_condition) {
   total += salary;
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer because it doesn't do the OP's homework for him.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a Scanner, below is the sample code.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner("salaries.txt");
double sum=0.0;
String line="";
while((line.hasNextDouble()){
  sum= sum+ line.nextDouble();
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Im using a scanner to read the salires from a .txt file

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Scanner` class, from `java.util`:

```
double sum = 0.0;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("yourFile.txt"));
while(scan.hasNextDouble()){
   sum += scan.nextDouble();
}
```

that's the basic code I can write for this problem.